# How to use a list with the format function

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x, string

Provided is a list of data about a store’s inventory where each item in the list represents the name of an item, how much is in stock, and how much it costs. Print out each item in the list with the same formatting, using the .format method (not string concatenation). For example, the first print statement should read The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD.

Below is the code I'm trying to use.

```
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 
15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]

for person in inventory:
    item = person[0]
    quantity = person[1]
    amount = person[2]
    print("The store has {} {}, each for {} USD.".format(item, quantity, 
    amount))
```

I can't figure out why it's only grabbing the first letter of the words.  Below is my output.
OUTPUT:

```
The store has s h, each for o USD.
The store has s h, each for i USD.
The store has s w, each for e USD.
The store has s c, each for a USD.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your format function is not wrong; the way you're parsing the item, quantity, and amount is wrong. If you look closely, `inventory` is a list of `string`s, not list of lists. That's why when you print `item`, it only prints out `"s"` because that is the first character in the string.

Try this:

```
inventory = [["shoes", "12", "29.99"], ["shirts", "20", "9.99"], ["sweatpants", "25", "15.00"], ["scarves", "13", "7.75"]]

for person in inventory:
    item = person[0]
    quantity = person[1]
    amount = person[2]
    print("The store has {} {}, each for {} USD.".format(item, quantity, 
    amount))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```py
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]

for person in inventory:
    person = person.split(',')
    item = person[0]
    quantity = person[1]
    amount = person[2]
    print("The store has {} {}, each for {} USD.".format(item, quantity, amount))

# output
# The store has shoes  12, each for  29.99 USD.
# The store has shirts  20, each for  9.99 USD.
# The store has sweatpants  25, each for   15.00 USD.
# The store has scarves  13, each for  7.75 USD.
```

Just split each and every item in the list in that way,

when you split `"shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99".split(',')`, you'll get `["shoes, "12", "29.99"]` kind of list. So no need to change your code, just add `person = person.split(',')` line after your for loop. When you loop it, every time you get a string. This is what happen each and every time when you looping.

```py
>>> 1st_str = "shoes, 12, 29.99"
>>> 1st_str[0]
's'
>>> 1st_str[1]
'h'
>>> 1st_str[2]
'o'
```

What I did was just split the string, then you easily access it as you wish.

```py
>>> 1st_str = "shoes, 12, 29.99"
>>> split_str = 1st_str.split(',')
>>> split_str
["shoes", "12", "29.99"]
>>> split_str[0]
'shoes'
>>> split_str[1]
'12'
>>> split_str[2]
'29.99'
```

Comment: @Dwr73244, I just updated the code to get more understand about the code for you!

Answer (score 1):

It's because, you're pointing at specific char, i.e. `person[0]` is the first character of `person` string. You would have to split person and then format the string, the following will do it without changing the `inventory` variable:

```
for person in inventory:
    person_data = person.split(" ")
    item = person_data[0]
    quantity = person_data[1]
    amount = person_data[2]
    print("The store has {} {}, each for {} USD.".format(item, quantity, 
    amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `person` is going to be each element in the list which is a string.

`person[0]` will return the first character of `person`

`person[1]` will return the second character of `person`

What you want to do is split the string by a comma.

You can do this using the `.split()` method on the string

`item, quantity, amount = person.split(",")`

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else's answers work perfectly, but I would recommend splitting on ", ", especially for the example that OP gave. It will keep there from being and extra whitespace or a comma than if you just split on "," or " ".

`item, quantity, amount = person.split(", ")`

or

````
person_data = person.split(", ")
item = person_data[0]
quantity = person_data[1]
amount = person_data[2]```
````